# Friendly URLs in Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Are there friendly URLs in Ionic Framework? I tried to use [ion-nav](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/) and [ion-tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) components and my URL does not change if I navigate to pages

```
this.nav.push(Page1);
// or
this.nav.setRoot(Page1);
```

URL is always http://localhost/ (I need http://localhost/page1, http://localhost/page2 etc)

Comment: What ionic version are you using? Lazy load is default feature in Ionic 3 and when you use it your url will response with the nav.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no.  There is probably some scripting work-around that might be able to mimic this kind of behavior, but it is not something that is native to the framework.

The Ionic Navcontroller uses html5 to transition between pages like a phone app instead of a desktop web browser.

What I would suggest is this:
Build a debug-only page that has launch buttons to all of the pages that you want to go to directly. Set this as the root page when you enter the app, and add to it as you bring in more pages. (In fact, these debug pages morph into my "secret pages" during development where I hide useful information for future debugging)

This is what my current one looks like:

[image]

That's probably the closest to what you want using the native tools. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote. (especially since I'm new and trying to build up reputation)  This seems to be well documented in the Ionic docs that they've abstracted away the url navigation of Ionic 1 to the Navcontroller of Ionic 2 and 3.  Is there a way to go directly to a page using the url? What did I miss?

Comment: Sorry for my downvote. But seem like you were not up to date. Deep link is a new and big feature of ionic 3. Please take a look at [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/link-to-pages-via-urls-with-deep-linking-in-ionic/)

Comment: ah.. outstanding!  Thanks!